# How do I texture map a cylinder in OpenGL?

Tags: iphone, android, graphics, opengl-es, 3d

I know how to do quads and that was pretty intuitive with the u,v texture coordinates but I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to think about the parametric representation of a cylinder

```
cylinder(u, v):
    x = r * cos(u * 2*pi)
    y = r * sin(u * 2*pi)
    z = v
```

**u** and **v** are exactly those values you'd use as texture coordinates.

Comment: Though this will only map the curved face of the cylinder. The end caps have to be mapped separately.

Comment: end caps texture coordinates would be just x,y – I strongly suggest not to map it radially.